# force input element's width to size to its content/value

Tags: html, css, input, autosize, angular-ui

I'm trying to unstyle an input element so that its text looks like plain/inline-text, and I've reset pretty much every css property it can have, but I can't get the input's width to adjust/shrink to its content (`input { width:auto; min-width:0; }` does not work). It obeys an arbitrary width like `input { width: 10px; }`, so obviously its width is adjustable.

I see [people trying to do it with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10833768/758177) (the fiddle from the answer doesn't work anymore), so I'm wondering if what I want is even possible.

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/2fQgY/)**.

Comment: It would be nice to see what you've tried so we aren't duplicating steps. Show the styles you're using.

Comment: @isherwood, oh sorry. I created a fiddle but forgot to link it in the question.

Comment: Is something wrong with defining a specific width?  Telling it to be 5em wide seems about right for any given date that would fill that text field.

Comment: @cimmanon, localisation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Played with this. Couldn't do it. What are you trying to achieve? Are you aware of the `contenteditable` attribute?

This might get you what you need.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: I think I have to use an input element (working with jqueryUI's datepicker and using a div causes the calendar to appear within the div).

Answer (score 1):

What if you just avoid the whole style snafu and do a little text shuffling? You already have everything you need with jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/2fQgY/8/

```
The date is <span class="dateSpoof"></span><input class="myDate" type="hidden" value="foo" />. 
Thanks for coming.

$('.myDate').datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'select...',
    onClose: function () {
        var dateText = $(this).val();
        $('.dateSpoof').html(dateText);
        $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').hide();
    },
    dateFormat: 'd M yy'
});
```

Here's an example that's resettable: http://jsfiddle.net/2fQgY/11

And here's one that's all text and nothing but text: http://jsfiddle.net/2fQgY/14

Comment: The problem with that is it's supposed to look like plain text (no button or input field). Also, once the data has been picked, it can't be re-picked (which will happen somewhat frequently in my app).

Comment: AngularUI (https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/tree/master/modules/directives/date) turns anything (except an input element) onto which the datepicker is applied into the container for the calendar: `<span ui-date="{options}">15 Feb 2013<span>` becomes to the calendar's container. I didn't mention AngularUI in my original question because my question wasn't about datepicker/AngularUI. I see if I can hack the lib to avoid this obnoxious behaviour (but the directive is rather complicated).

Comment: kind of…i'd have to write my own directive to use your method.

Comment: Fair enough. It was a fun little project anyway.

Comment: isherwodd: I just discovered angular-ui's jq directive (https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/tree/4d8c6fb8b54dc2e021b32029fe5a79d567888987/modules/directives/jq), so I may be able to use your method after all :)